Why does the SELECT OFFSET take the same time as the SELECT without OFFSET?
id is the primary key.
EXPLAIN SELECT id FROM data
LIMIT 1000000

Limit  (cost=0.44..18840.00 rows=1000000 width=8)
EXPLAIN SELECT id FROM data
LIMIT 1000000 OFFSET 1000000

Limit  (cost=18840.00..37679.56 rows=1000000 width=8)
Ok, but
EXPLAIN SELECT id FROM data
LIMIT 1000000 OFFSET 2000000

Limit  (cost=37679.56..56519.12 rows=1000000 width=8)
Why not just something near 18840
EXPLAIN SELECT id FROM data
LIMIT 1000000 OFFSET 3000000

Limit  (cost=56519.12..75358.69 rows=1000000 width=8)
etc.
If I need get 1M and skip 10M it takes hours.
Expecting cost=0.44 or cost=18840

Offset dictates the bottom of the cost range, because you want to read that many rows just to skip them. Limit dictates the actual width of the cost range, because you want to read up to that many rows from the point where offset finished skipping. Consider a cursor or keyset pagination instead - it'll use the index behind the primary key and not try to read everything offset wants to throw away.

Your title is about time, but in the body you don't mention any timings.

I always thought that PRIMARY KEY is the index by default.
CREATE INDEX resolves everything.

@bashism Primary key means it's unique not null and the unique part is handled by an index. In the example you've shown, you were doing nothing that would convince Postgres to use either the pk or any other index so I don't see how creating another one resolves anything. Would you care to share what you were really doing, what you altered and how the result changed?

Could you please share the results from the different queries, using explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for each query? And the DDL for the table and indexes involved. cost depends on your configuration and doesn't tell you anything (!) about time.

That is unavoidable. In order to skip the first three million result rows, you first have to calculate them. Otherwise, you don't know what the first three million rows are.
So
SELECT ... OFFSET 3000000 LIMIT 1000000

is approximately as expensive as
SELECT ... LIMIT 4000000

See this article for a discussion of alternatives.
